# How to modify CodeIgniter calendar to handle multiple events per day?

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am creating a calendar without jquery calendar plugin. I could retrieve the data which is in the database to the calendar. But when there are multiple data per day only one data comes to the calendar view. I want it to be like this when there is multiple data.

[image: expected]

But what i am getting is this when there are multiple data

[image: current]

the day 16 has every four data.but it shows only one. If anyone has an idea about this it would be help me.

following are my code

**Controller**

```
<?php

class My_calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($year = null, $month = null) {
        echo "My calendar project";
        $this->showcal($year, $month);
    }

    public function showcal($year = null, $month = null) {
        $this->load->model('mycal_model');
        $data['calendar'] = $this->mycal_model->generate($year, $month);

        $this->load->view('mycal', $data);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

        <style type="text/css">



            #body{
                margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
            }



            #container{
                margin: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
            }


            .calendar{
                /*           background-color: yellow;*/
            }
            table.calendar{
                margin: auto;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .calendar .days td {
                width:80px;
                height: 90px;
                padding: 4px;
                border:  1px solid #999;
                vertical-align:  top;
                background-color: #DEF;

            }
            .calendar .days td:hover{
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            .calendar .highlight {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #EF1BAC;
            }
            .calendar .content .gk_am{
                float: left;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                background-color: #D0D0D0;
            }
            .calendar .content .gk_pm{
                float: right;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            .calendar .content .rp_am{
                float: left;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                background-color: gray;
            }

            .calendar .content .rp_pm{
                float: right;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                background-color: #D893A1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="body">
                <?PHP echo $calendar; ?>

            </div>


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class mycal_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->mycal_model();
    }

    function mycal_model() {

        $this->conf = array(
            'show_next_prev' => True,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'index.php/my_calendar/index/'
        );

        $this->conf['template'] = '
            {table_open}<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="calendar">{/table_open}

            {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

            {heading_previous_cell}<th class="prev_sign"><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th class="next_sign"><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

            //Deciding where to week row start
            {week_row_start}<tr class="week_name" >{/week_row_start}
            //Deciding  week day cell and  week days
            {week_day_cell}<td >{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            //week row end
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

            {cal_row_start}<tr class= "days">{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

            {cal_cell_content}
                <div class="day_num">{day}
                </div>
                <div class= "content">{content}
                </div>
            {/cal_cell_content}

            {cal_cell_content_today}
            <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
             <div class= "content">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content_today}

            {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
            ';
    }

    function get_calendar_data($year, $month) {

        $query = $this->db->select('date_cal,title,type')->from('reservations')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
        $cal_data = array();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            }
        }



        return $cal_data;
    }

    function generate($year, $month) {


        $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);

        $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);

        return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $cal_data);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show all four boxes for the dates which has data, try to change the get_calendar_data() foreach as below,

```
$content = "";
$lastDay = -1;
$index = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

        if($lastDay != intval(substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2))){       
            if($index > 0 ){
               if($content != ''){
                   $cal_data[$lastDay] = $content;
                   $content = '';
               }
            }
            $index = 0;               
        }


        if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $content .= '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $content .= '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        }else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $content .= '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';                
        } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $content .= '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';                
        }

        $lastDay = intval(substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2));
        $index++;     

    }

    if($lastDay != -1 && $content != ''){
        $cal_data[$lastDay] = $content;
    }
```

Let me know whether it works now or not.