# How to return multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have following method in my controller.

```
function get_calendar_data($year, $month) {

        $query = $this->db->select('date_cal,title,type')->from('reservations')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
        $cal_data = array();
        $cal_data2 = array();
        $cal_data3 = array();
        $cal_data4 = array();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            }
        }

        return $cal_data;
    }
```

I want to return all values in $cal_data,$cal_data2,$cal_data3 and $cal_data4.
Is there any way to do that??

Comment: Put everything in one array and return that.

Comment: Your question is answered or you did ask wrong. Please accept the answer that best answers your question.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Any of these methods didn't work for me.

Comment: @IshaniPathinayake: Then you should maybe rewrite your question. Try to be very clear on what your desired output is.
All Answers return all th values in $cal_data,$cal_data2,$cal_data3 and $cal_data4 in different ways. Be clear on what you expect and what in the given answers derives from that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making such kind of array normalize your array as

```
$result = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
        $result['cal_data'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
    } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
        $result['cal_data2'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
    } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
        $result['cal_data3'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
    } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
        $result['cal_data4'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
    }
}

return $result;
```

**Edited**

```
return array_merge($cal_data,$cal_data2,$cal_data3,$cal_data4);
```

OR

```
$result['cal_data'] = $cal_data;
$result['cal_data2'] = $cal_data2;
$result['cal_data3'] = $cal_data3;
$result['cal_data4'] = $cal_data4;

return $result;
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work for me

Comment: Did you get any error. Or try my edited answer

Comment: I think this should work. but it doesn't give me the expected output  because the way i am checking condition is wrong. Here if the 1st condition is true other conditions won't be checked. I want all conditions to be checked. any idea to do that?

Comment: You can use `switch case`

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

> Values are returned by using the optional return statement. Any type may be returned, including arrays and objects. This causes the function to end its execution immediately and pass control back to the line from which it was called. See [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) for more information.

Though, you can Return a single array which contains that all arrays,

```
return [ $cal_data, $cal_data2, $cal_data3, $cal_data4 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
function get_calendar_data($year, $month) {

    $query = $this->db->select('date_cal,title,type')->from('reservations')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
    $cal_data = array(
        "GK_AM" => array(),
        "GK_PM" => array(),
        "RP_AM" => array(),
        "RP_PM" => array(),
    );

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data['GK_AM'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data['GK_PM'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data['RP_AM'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data['RP_PM'][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $cal_data;
}
```

...or, if there are only four options (GKAM, GKPM, RPAM, RPPM), then this is even shorter...

```
function get_calendar_data($year, $month) {

    $query = $this->db->select('date_cal,title,type')->from('reservations')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
    $cal_data = array(
        "GK_AM" => array(),
        "GK_PM" => array(),
        "RP_AM" => array(),
        "RP_PM" => array(),
    );

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $cal_data[$row->title. '_' . $row->type][substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
    }

    return $cal_data;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me :(

Comment: @IshaniPathinayake, what error or behavior are you getting?

Comment: For my previous code i am getting only one array data. when i use your code I don't get any data.

Comment: `$cal_data` is clearly being loaded and returned. What way are you testing to see if there is data in the array? Please show code.

Comment: refer this link. here is my full code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977437/how-to-modify-codeigniter-calendar-to-handle-multiple-events-per-day

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to review your full code. My question is what way are you testing to see if there's data in the array?

Comment: I think this should work. but it doesn't give me the expected output  because the way i am checking condition is wrong. Here if the 1st condition is true other conditions won't be checked. I want all conditions to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values for the same array index, you can define a dynamic array.

ps: Notice the [] dynamic allocation.

Example:

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)][] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)][] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)][] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)][] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $cal_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check all condition then pass all condition in if not elseif

```html
$data['cal_data'] = $cal_data;
$data['cal_data2'] = $cal_data2;
$data['cal_data3'] = $cal_data3;
$data['cal_data4'] = $cal_data4;

return $data;
```