# How to return multiple arrays from a function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having this function in my controller.

```
function get_data($year, $month) {

        $query = $this->db->select('date,name,type')->from('books')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
        $data = array();
        $data2 = array();
        $data3 = array();


        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->name == 'AA' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $data[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="aa_am">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->name == 'AA' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $data2[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="aa_pm">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } else if ($row->name == 'BB' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $data3[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="bb_am">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } 
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

I want to retrieve all data which is in $data,$data1 and $data2 at the same time. Is it possible to do it?? If anyone have an idea it would be a help for me.

Comment: `return array($data,$data2,$data3);` , other option is `return array_merge($data,$data1,$data2)`. array merge have chances of data lose in case of any key is same.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework or something? because same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981819/how-to-return-multiple-arrays) was posted with same code

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I don't know what result you expect by combining all data which is in $data, $data1 and $data2.

but you can try `array_merge(array1,array2,array3...)`  function if you want all data where key starting from 0 and increases by 1 for each value.

Or else you can create another array with all data values like,

`return array("data" => $data, "data1" => $data1, "data2" => $data2)`

by this way you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way,

```
function get_data($year, $month) {

    $query = $this->db->select('date,name,type')->from('books')->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after')->get();
    $data = array();
    $data1 = array();
    $data2 = array();


    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->name == 'AA' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $data[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="aa_am">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->name == 'AA' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $data1[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="aa_pm">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } else if ($row->name == 'BB' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $data2[substr($row->date, 8, 2)] = '<div class="bb_am">' . $row->name . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } 
    }
$return['data']=$data;
$return['data1']=$data1;
$return['data2']=$data2;
    return $data;
}
```

you can acces in view as varible,

```
$data['index'], $data1['index'], $data2['index']
```

if you want to merge them then,

```
array_merge($data,$data1,$data2);
```

Comment: I think this should work. but it doesn't give me the expected output  because the way i am checking condition is wrong. Here if the 1st condition is true other conditions won't be checked. I want all conditions to be checked. any idea to do that?

Comment: try to debug it and check how data comes. using `print_r($query->result())` and then `print_r($row->name)`